# Change File Open Dialog to have Date Updated/Modified instead of Date Added

Tags: finder

For the `Finder` app the `Date Modified` is shown as desired:

[image]

However in the `File Open` dialog it is not:

[image]

How can the `File Open` dialog be adjusted to show `Date Modified` instead of `Date Added` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just the same as in the Finder - right click anywhere on the header bar [Name, Size, Kind etc] & you can add or remove data types as you wish

[image]

You can then drag the columns into your preferred order & sort by clicking any header.